# What is the most efficient way to apply "if-then" condition to all elements in Octave vector?

Tags: octave, linear-algebra

I have a vector of floats, each element being between 0 and 1.  I wish to change those elements that are greater than (and equal) to 0.5 to be 1, and those that are less then 0.5 to 0.

Is there an Octave function that will let me do this in a vectorized way as opposed to using a for-loop?

thanks

Answer (score 7):

Solution: I used a boolean-returning condition within the line that generated the vector in the first place:`myVector = (sigmoid(vec1*vec2)>=0.5)`